# Unable to locate package postgresql-server-dev-15 while installing PostgreSQL 15 using pdpg?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql-15

I am trying to upgrade PostgreSQL to version 15 but some packages from 14 seems to be missing. There was `postgresql-server-dev-14` in PostgreSQL 14. Trying to upgrade, I tried:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-server-dev-15
```

but got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-server-dev-15
```

I use [PGDG apt repository for Debian/Ubuntu](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) (Ubuntu 22.04). Currently, the only related packages I could find are:

```
postgresql-server-dev-10   postgresql-server-dev-14   postgresql-server-dev-9.0  postgresql-server-dev-9.4
postgresql-server-dev-11   postgresql-server-dev-8.2  postgresql-server-dev-9.1  postgresql-server-dev-9.5
postgresql-server-dev-12   postgresql-server-dev-8.3  postgresql-server-dev-9.2  postgresql-server-dev-9.6
postgresql-server-dev-13   postgresql-server-dev-8.4  postgresql-server-dev-9.3  postgresql-server-dev-all
```

*How do I install the `postgresql-server-dev` package for PostgreSQL 15?*